# Session level exception

Tags: asp.net

I am having an page. I need to capture the exception which is thrown due to time out..

Is there any exception message like System.Applicationexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Application_Error event in Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                var exception = Server.GetLastError();
                LogException(exception);
    }
```

And after catching log this exception or even mail it :)